# How do I know when a user has reached the end of the text in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextview

My users are reading readonly text in a UITextView. When they have finished reading a selection and have scrolled to the bottom, I would like to be able to display a Completed Reading button that animates up from the bottom. How can I detect when the user has scrolled to the end of the text?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969970/detect-uitextview-scroll-location ?

Comment: `UITextView` extends `UIScrollView`. Make use of the scrollview delegates to know when it has scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, -scrollViewDidEndDecelerating does work better than -scrollViewDidScroll but it also fires if the user scrolls back up and so I need a way to discern if the text that is visible is actually the last part of the text.  I've tried using a non-visible end_marker_string but it's searching all of the text instead of just the text that is visible.

Comment: @ujell - Yes.  I had not seen that question but I have tried that method.  I'm not sure why they said that it worked for them. When I used it, the NSLog statement was printed every time so this method of seeing if you are at the bottom does not work.  I tried it again to make sure.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm using this code within -scrollViewDidEndDescelerating.  I have a method that appends an ENDMARKERSTRING that is called by -viewDidLoad                                                        NSString * strVisibleText = [self visibleTextInTextView:self.textView];
    
    if ([strVisibleText rangeOfString:END_MARKER_STRING].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"string does not contain END_MARKER_STRING");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"string contains END_MARKER_STRING");
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey just add UIScrollViewDelegate and this provide's below method that would be called as scroll end reaches.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

So give it a try and let me know if anything.

Comment: Thanks, that is the event that I am using because it fires less often that -scrollViewDidScroll but it also fires when the user scrolls back up so it is not, in itself, a reliable way to know if you are the end of the text in the textView.

Comment: I was wrong!  I had some other noise in my NSLogs that made me think it was firing twice but when I removed them, this turned out to be a perfectly clean solution.  Thank you, marking as correct :)

Comment: Within the method, in case anyone else needs it: //determines if user has scrolled to the bottom
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"at bottom");
    }