# How to know textView is scroll to bottom?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textView , and it's text content will increase .
I want to know how to set a bool value , like isTextViewScrollToBottom:Bool
when textView is scroll to bottom, then isTextViewScrollToBottom = true
when textView is leave bottom, then isTextViewScrollToBottom = false

now, I only know can use scrollViewDelegate func like:

scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView),

scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView),

scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)

and I try this:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    checkIsScrollToBottom(scrollView)
}
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    checkIsScrollToBottom(scrollView)
}
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
   checkIsScrollToBottom(scrollView)
}

fileprivate func checkIsScrollToBottom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    if textViewForChatContent.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y == 301 {
        isScrollToBottom = true
        print("isScrollToBottom=\(isScrollToBottom)")
    }else{
        isScrollToBottom = false
        print("isScrollToBottom=\(isScrollToBottom)")
    }
}
```

but this Judgment is not good use  for all device.
is someone know better Judgment, can know  textView is scroll to bottom?

thanks!

Comment: The duplicate is in Objective-C , but since the solution is just a basic one line calculation of the scrollOffset, I marked it as a duplicate.

Comment: thank a lot , it solve my problem!

Comment: @Sneak maybe a swift version of this question would be more friendly to beginners, I used to freak out about OC code :)

Comment: @BrightFuture Go ahead and port it to Swift and answer here, DanielTing could accept it as the answer. I removed the duplicate tag. here is the Obj-C version : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969970/detect-uitextview-scroll-location , or update the existing question with a Swift version (?)

Comment: @Sneak there's a `Swift` tag on this question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969970/detect-uitextview-scroll-location)

You can use this function:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {

        print( "View scrolled to the bottom" )

    }
}
```